# Use Array as datasource for a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, sharepoint-2013, u2

I am very new to web services I am trying to create a web service hopefulle REST if possible to Receive an array from a subroutine(U2 sub but that doesn't matter right now) and create like a list in sharepoint using that web service as an external data source can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you planned on writing you own RESTful web server then I agree with the suggestion to use UniObjects.

Yet, you do not need to write your own RESTFul server, you can use "Rocket U2 RESTFul Web Services".

It is in "Rocket U2 DBTools" which can be downloaded from:
http://www.rocketsoftware.com/trials?page=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out UniObjects (which comes with the Basic Developers Toolkit, I believe) the or the [Rocket U2 Toolkit for .NET](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-u2/rocket-u2-toolkit-net)? Those will provide you with the libraries you need to exercise your your subroutine and to fetch out the UniArray object from the parameters therein.

Using one of these methods you should be able to format your data into however you need it using the .NET framework. That is really the hard part of web-servicing through a U2 product. Well that and insuring your internal data structures aren't an inherited hot mess. :-)